# C++: casted char pointer points to unexpected part of the data

Tags: c++

When I try to run the code below:

```
void* data = new char[SIZE]();
int16_t* num = static_cast<int16_t*>(data);
char* c = static_cast<char*>(data);
num[0] = 49;
num[1] = 50;
num[2] = 48;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    cout << num[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    cout << "'" << c[i] << "' ";
cout << endl;
c[1] = 1;
cout << num[0] << endl;
```

I got some unexpected result:

```
49 50 48  
'1' '' '2' '0' ''  
305
```

So the first line of the output confirms that `num[0] == 49` (int16), which in binary form is `00000000 00110001`. Converted to `char`, the first byte should be an unprintable character and the second byte should be `'1'`. But the second line shows that it's the other way around.

Also, the third line shows the attempt to change the second byte to `00000001` changed the first byte instead. I expected it to be `00000000 00000001`, but the int16 value is 305 which is `00000001 00110001`.

What's going on here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the way the computer keeps information in its memory, a.k.a [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/).

Here is a illustration of a 16bit variable in both big/little-endian notations:

[image]

In your case, since you are setting the values through a `uint16_t` variable, and your machine is using little-endian, each pair is stored in reverse order, thus, the '1' is printed before the unprintable character.

**Extra reading (Elaborating Martin Bonner's comment)**

For 16bit variable, there are only two possible byte endianness notations, those are the ones presented above. For 32bit variables, there are a total of 12 possible byte orderings, and at least three of them are/were used: Big-Endian, Little-Endian and PDP-Endian (a.k.a Middle-Endian):

[image]

Comment: The OP should be aware that while there are only two possible endiannesses for `uint16_t` (little and big), there are actually *twelve* possible byte ordering for `uint32_t`, and *at least three* have actually been used

Comment: There are two _sane_ possibilities, sure. But I don't believe the Standard specifies that the byte values of a `uint16_t` are `v>>8` and `v&0xff` in some order.

Comment: @aschepler, I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment, could you elaborate?

Comment: [basic.fundamental]/7 does say "The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system." But as far as I can see, the 16 bits in a `uint16_t` could _technically_ be in any order and do not necessarily relate to the order of bits within an `uint8_t`.

Comment: @aschepler, thanks for the comment. I added the term `byte endianness notations` to be clear I'm not referring to possible bit endianness notations.